# Use definition of differentiability to prove $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}:(x,y) \to x^2 y^2$ is differentiable at any point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

By using the definition of a differentiable function prove
$g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}:(x,y) \to x^2 y^2$ is differentiable at any point $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and check this answer by computing Jacobi Matrix = $g'$ at $(x_0, y_0)$.

Here, I know the definition of a differentiable function and to set up the question using the formula that needs to be satisfied
$f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)= L((x,y)-(x_0,y_0)) + r((x,y),(x_0,y_0))$.
I believe this is the right setup but I haven't done a question before in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and when I do my calculations I get stuck at working out what is L and r despite in the second part I can work out the jacobi matrix $g'=(2xy^2\ \ 2yx^2)$ and so $g'(x_0,y_0) =(2x_0y_0^2\ \ 2y_0x_0^2)$.

Thanks in advance as I have really bit a brick wall with this one :)

Answer (score 1):

First, note that every linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has the form $L(x,y)=ax+by$, where $a=L(1,0),\,b=L(0,1)$. Now, if $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$, show that $a=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0),\,b=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0).$ Hence, in your particular case, you get $L$ and $r$ will be $f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)-L(x-x_0,y-y_0)$.

Comment: How do you show that a equals partial derivative of f with respect to x at (x₀,y₀) and b equals partial derivative of f with respect to y at (x₀, y₀)? I am unsure how to link these two concepts together I just think I understand the formula and definitions that have to be satisfied for differentiability.

Comment: The limit $\frac{f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)-L(x-x_0,y-y_0)}{||(x-x_0,y-y_0||)}$ is $0$ as $(x,y)$ goes to $(x_0,y_0)$. Now take the "canonical paths" $(x,y_0)$ and $(x_0,y)$.